# Javafx setting a background

Tags: java, javafx, background, fxml

I'm trying to give my borderpane a background with the help of fxml.
I have a view and a controller. 
I think you have to say in fxml: borderPane.setBackground(new Background(myBI));

but I do not know how.
using css is not an option.

View:

```
package application;


import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Layout_play.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test");
        primaryStage.setFullScreen(true);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 1280, 720));
        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public class PlayController {

    @FXML
    private Label label;
    @FXML
    private TextField textfield;

    @FXML
    private BackgroundImage myBI= new BackgroundImage(new Image("/Background.png",1280,720,false,true),
            BackgroundRepeat.REPEAT, BackgroundRepeat.NO_REPEAT, BackgroundPosition.DEFAULT,
              BackgroundSize.DEFAULT);



    @FXML
    private void handleButtonAction(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("You clicked me!");
        label.setText("Hello  " + textfield.getText());
    }
}
```

and as last fxml

```
<BorderPane fx:controller="application.PlayController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
    prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" >

    <top>
        <Text text="java-Buddy"/>
    </top>
    <left>
        <Label text="Who are you?"/>
    </left>
    <center>
        <TextField id="textfield" fx:id="textfield"/>
    </center>
    <right>
        <Button id="button"  text="Click Me!"
            onAction="#handleButtonAction" fx:id="button"/>
    </right>
    <bottom>
        <Label id="label" fx:id="label"/>
    </bottom>

</BorderPane>
```

Comment: Using the `initialize` method to do this is not an option either???

Comment: Why is using CSS not an option? CSS is the recommended approach for this.

Comment: Its for school and they disallowed using css. 
how does the initialize methode work?

Comment: Fabian is just referring to the standard `initialize()` method in the [controller](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers). You can probably also do this in FXML, but it's really ugly. I'm not going to attempt to post that as an answer as it is of no use in real life, imho.

Comment: As of java 10.0.1 `FXMLLoader` fails to use the constructor.

Comment: Does the "No CSS" rule prevent you using inline css (i.e. `<BorderPane style="-fx-background-image ... ;">`)? You can do that directly in the FXML file, with no external CSS file. It's probably the 2nd cleanest way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you can't use CSS, this isn't going to be pretty.

You already have defined a `BackgroundImage` as `myBI`, which you can use to set a background for your element.

Give your BorderPane an `fx:id` for example

```
<BorderPane fx:id="bPane" fx:controller="application.PlayController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
prefHeight="200" prefWidth="320" >
```

then from there add

```
@FXML
private Borderpane bPane;
```

to your Controller class.

finally, create method

```
@FXML
public void initialize(){
    bPane.setBackground(new Background(myBI));
}
```